# SyntaxError: invalid syntax [in python code]

Tags: ipython

code is:

```
cat_list = [k for k, v in cat_counter.()[:50]]
```

Error is as follows:

> File "", line 1
>       cat_list = [k for k, v in cat_counter.()[:50]]
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The error says it all. `[k for k, v in cat_counter()[:50]]` Remove that DOT!

Answer (score 1):

The `cat_counter` function would be defined like this:

```
def cat_counter():
    # Make function
```

Thus, simply **remove the dot** to properly call the function:

```
cat_list = [k for k, v in cat_counter()[:50]]
```